# Are Wittgenstein's propositions about death incompatible with momentariness?

Tags: time, wittgenstein, death, buddhism

[Are Wittgenstein's propositions](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/5740/5740-pdf.pdf?session_id=dea156ed05c91a66b937826e68af03b1f8e78c53) about death incompatible with momentariness?

I think mean that **death, which is a cessation that is not lived through, cannot change life, and we are immortal outside space and time**.

[image]

I take 6.431 to elaborate on, show the meaning of, 6.41, and how things that cannot be expressed in language do not change or have ends within them, like life and the will.

---

Is this incompatible with Buddhist momentariness? The immediate [cessation](https://ahandfulofleaves.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/the-buddhist-doctrine-of-momentariness_vonrospatt.pdf) of things which

> pass out of existence as soon as they  have  originated  and in this
>   sense are momentary. As an entity vanishes,  it gives rise to a new 
>   entity of almost the same nature  which  originates  immediately
>   afterwards... This doctrine of momentariness  entails  that change is 
>   not constituted by the transmutation of persisting entities, but by
>   the  qualitative  difference  between  earlier and later  entities
>   within a series.

---

- Momentariness means life immediately ends.
- Wittgenstein means that life in the present does not demise (the cessation of the world we cannot experience).
- Then life in the present, "eternal life", is only ever in the present and does not demise.

Comment: "As an entity vanishes, it gives rise to a new entity" vs "cessation is all there is to change", you see the problem? And what is the question aside from "is it possible" mixing of Wittgenstein and Buddhism? Anything is possible.

Comment: i think the right answer is that momentariness is a metaphysical doctrine and so unsuitable for wittgenstein.

Comment: My guess at the moment is they do not overlap enough to be incompatible with each other. Wittgenstein's world is like the Buddhist's mind. That is where I see the possible connection. +1 for the reference to momentariness.

Comment: I do not think they are incompatible, but I think maybe you have another question here or something else you might be trying to get at? The question as asked is hard to answer.

Comment: Wittgenstein always struck me as a kind of closet Buddhist....